# How can I prove $\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}\neq \sin(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}\neq \sin(x) $$

I can plot the graphs tells me why this is correct, But how can I theoretically prove this ?

Comment: The LHS is always positive (by definition of $\sqrt{}$), $\sin x$ isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of people like to consider the square root $f: x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ as the inverse function of the square $g: x\mapsto x^2$. This is true if you consider $g$ as a function on $I=[0,\infty)$. Then you get $f\circ g(x)=x=g\circ f(x)$ for all $x\in I$.

Nevertheless, you can consider the composition $f\circ g$ not just on $I$ but on $\mathbb R$ and you get $f\circ g(x)=|x|$, therefore $f\circ g$ is not the identity on $\mathbb R$. For a function $h$ we can conclude $f\circ g\circ h=h$ is true if and only if $h(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$, because if there exists $x_0$ such that $h(x_0)<0$, then $f\circ g\circ h(x_0)=|h(x_0)|=-h(x_0)>0>h(x_0)$.

And that is the case for $\sin$ on $\mathbb R$ since $\sin\left(\frac32\pi\right)=-1<0$ and therefore $\sqrt{\sin^2\left(\frac32\pi\right)}=\left|\sin\left(\frac32\pi\right)\right|=1\neq -1=\sin\left(\frac32\pi\right)$.

Otherwise you can consider $\sin$ restricted on $J=[0,\pi]$ and you get $\sin(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in J$ and then $\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}=|\sin(x)|=\sin(x)$.

You see that the statement depends on the domain of $x$.

Answer (score 5):

$\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}=|\sin(x)| \neq \sin(x)$ in general as for some real $x$'s, $\sin(x) <0$ (for example for $x=\frac{3\pi}{2}$), while $|\sin(x)|\geq 0 $ $\forall x$